# Selenium IDE - Radio button error

Tags: selenium-ide

Selenium IDE - When running the script I am getting error for the radio button in selenium IDE. In my script, it’s required to select radio button (selecting dates) but its error message “[error] Element id=radio250 not found”. it stops the execution here. even if i use another date, it still stops on the same point. How to change the value in dynamic ?

I am new in the testing industry and would appreciate any help on this one. I know it has something to do with xpath but I don’t know how to use it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below alternative to locate radio button

```
//input[@type='radio']
//input[@name='name_attribute' and @value='value_attribute']
```

OR by xpath

```
xpath=(//*[@class="name of the class"])
```

Or if your page is not fully loaded then also you will face same problem - element not found.
If such situation is there put pause command before execution of command for radio button

Or provide the HTML of the element you are trying to locate

Comment: Thanks for your reply rohit, xpath solved the problem. i am new so didnt knew much about xpath. firebug and firepath addons solved the problem and gave me understanding as well. Thanks again.

Comment: @saurabh - as solution works..i think you should accept answer  ;)